# ImageUrl lost on postback with dynamic controls, but textboxes keep their value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button that adds an already defined usercontrol programtically. I am rebuilding each control on Postback and they show up fine.  If I put text in the textbox it shows up fine, however my images are losing their url.  Any idea why or how I can fix this?

I tried adding AJAX updatepanel to see if that would help, but it does not.

To further explain - I have a button that after clicks set the url of the image - I also put this value in the textbox just to see if the same thing happens - after postback, my textbox still has the value, but the image does not - and all of my other ASP.Net images lose their image and they are defined right on the controls (ie: ImageUrl)

--- update
OK, I have found some more insight to my issue - some solutions but still one problem remains.

The reason the images were loosing their url is because they were  and not ASP.Net images - ASP.Net remembers the values when they are recreated on postback - however the Main image that im changing via javascript looses its value - I'm very certain this is because of using javascript to change it, on post back it reverts back to the previous value... so for a solution I will try to stuff it in a hidden value, then use that value on postback to define the ImageUrl of the image...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct `<img>` is an html control, while `<asp:Image>` is a server control.  As long as server controls have viewstate enabled they will keep their values during postbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that changing an image's URL via JavaScript will not get it returned during the postback as this is not a form value. Therefore, it will be lost forever if you do not save it into a form field, such as the hidden field that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Image is not form field. That is why it's value is never posted back to server.

The reason your asp:Image controls retain value during postback is because they are stored in viewstate (which is stored in hidden field). When you click button this viewstate is posted back to server, and asp.net sets the ImageUrl property of image control from viewstate in early events of page lifecycle.

In short the server side form controls values are available after postback. Same way if you have normal html form fields (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp), you will get it's value using Request.Form collection.

You are setting your Image's src using javascript (and which is obviously not in original viewstate), that is why you are not getting it's value in postback. You should use Hidden Field to set value using javascript, which can be available after postback.